# How to get an equation for a graph with saddle point that hits 2 other points?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am trying to create a graph that has the points (0/3) and (30/-3) and hits the x-axis in (15/0). This point (15/0) is also the saddle point.

Because of the saddle point, I figured out that it needs to look like this:
f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d

With these information, I got these equations:

- d = 3
- a*30^3+b*30^2+c*30+d = -3
- a*15^3+b*15^2+c*15+d = 0
- 3*a*15^2+2*b*15+c = 0 (first derivative)
- 6*a*15+2*b = 0 (second derivative)

How can I get the values of a,b,c and d now?
I tried it, but failed.
Are my information (the 2 points + the saddle point) even enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

You want the saddle point at $(15,0)$, so you try $a(x-15)^3$. You want it to go through $(0,3)$ so you find $a=-3/15^3$. Hence you get $$3\left(\frac{x}{15}-1\right)^3$$